# Set parameter value in SSRS report in sharepoint integrated mode with dropdown

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, parameter-passing, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS report, deployed in sharepoint integrated mode. It has a parameter ProjectId which is associated with a dataset means it has a drop down where the user can select any project.

I want to pass the parameter value from URL. When the parameter was not associated with a dataset, means it was a textbox. I was able to set the parameter value using rp: in URL but when I associate it with dataset it stop working.

Can anyone help me for this.

Comment: Make sure you are passing the VALUE of the drop down, not the label.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check Query String (URL) Filter web part for this.

You could check below similar thread.

http://www.epmpartners.com.au/blog/connect-query-string-web-part-to-ssrs-report-viewer-web-part/